# Split array list into another array list using common expression in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array list in java named temp that contains the following:

```
temp [abc,123,456,678,abc,xyz,tyh,479,572,4891,asx,abc,4r65,abc,xg,5684]
```

Now I want to split the above array into another array list like below:

```
newtemp[0]=[abc,123,456,678]
newtemp[1]=[abc,xyz,tyh,479,572,4891,asx]
newtemp[2]=[abc,4r65]
newtemp[3]=[abc,xg,5684]
```

I want to split the array using 'abc' as the common breaker. How can I achieve this? It seems pretty complex to me. I am unable to build upon a logic for it.

Comment: what is the type of `temp` and `newtemp` and what is the the dimention of `newtemp`,your question is unclear for me whether you want to insert array in `newtemp[index]` or a String

Comment: another case of ask a question and run away every user has to understand after asking a question you have to stick around for a few minutes to clear the your question doubts this would help only to you for getting more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing that when I ran `toString()` on an `ArrayList` of items I got

```
[abc, 123, 456, 678, abc, xyz, tyh, 479, 572, 4891, asx, abc, 4r65, abc, xg, 5684]
```

This was how I decided to treat the data, which lead me to believe that the end result was to have `List<List<String>>` and each element of the outer list would have an inner sublist beginning with "abc".  This is accomplished with a single `for` loop that iterates through temp, and a new sublist is created whenever the loop runs across an "abc".  You'll see that my List begins with ["aaa", "123"] and these items get skipped until we come across the first "abc".

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("aaa", "123", "abc", "123", "456",
                "678", "abc", "xyz", "tyh", "479", "572", "4891", "asx", "abc",
                "4r65", "abc", "xg", "5684"));
        List<List<String>> newTemp = new ArrayList();

        for (String tmp : temp) {
            // Start a new sublist
            if (tmp.contentEquals("abc")) {
                newTemp.add(new ArrayList());
            }

            // Add to the newest sublist
            if (newTemp.size() > 0) {
                newTemp.get(newTemp.size() - 1).add(tmp);
            }
        }

        for (List<String> list : newTemp) {
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
[abc, 123, 456, 678]
[abc, xyz, tyh, 479, 572, 4891, asx]
[abc, 4r65]
[abc, xg, 5684]
```

Comment: in the following lines i get errors:                     newTemp.add(new ArrayList());                    no suitable method found for add                                      newTemp.get(newTemp.size() - 1).add(tmp);                  cannot find symbol               and in                  for (List<String> list : newTemp) {                                                                                 String cannot be converted to list<string>

Comment: @HelloMan You're going to have to post your code in your question.  My code is tested and works.  Also, if you're using the code I provided, do you have the necessary import lines to use List, ArrayList, and Arrays.asList?  import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

Comment: i simplified my problem and posted it. real problem is too complex to understand.code would be too complex to understand as it a part of web application.

Comment: @HelloMan Make sure you have the needed imports. See my updated response.

Comment: your code is working code. I got it working by modifying it according to my web application. I only had to change minor things like list names and stuff and nothing in the logic part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Make these variables as static
private static int index = 0;
private static int count = 0;

//logic 
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
    if (temp.get(i).equals(temp.get(index)) && i > 0) {
        System.out.println(temp.subList(index, count));
        index = i;
    }
    count++;
}
System.out.println("last list =  " + temp.subList(index, count));
```

You can store each sublist in an arraylist which you have created.

```
Hope it helps!!
```

Comment: This does not work if the original list does not begin with "abc"